# Moving foobar2000 to another drive (+ cant listen to previous music, + global hotkeys not working all the time)

Tags: audio, hotkeys, music, foobar2000

I have [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org) as well as ALL of my music on `I:` drive. Now if I would simply copy all my music along with foobar to my `C:` drive, my music wouldnt be played as foobar2000 would read it `I:\something\music`.

One simple thing, I think, I could do is to just rename the `C:` drive to `I:` and match the file name path. But I would still like to know if there is another way to get my music playing from another location. Because I will share my music folder with a friend and he most certainly will not change his drive letters. Or maybe I’m just an idiot and this is really easy to do.

Also, I have no idea why, when I click on the previous button in foobar2000 nothing is played. It does the same thing the Stop button does.

And I’d like to mention that sometimes my buttons dont work. I made sure to check the “global hotkey” checkmark in foobar2000. This happens only when running games.

Oh just on a side note, when are we getting foobar2000 for Android? I think the fundraiser ended quite a while ago, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I move my music folders?

You need to configure the Foobar2000 "Music Folders" to point to their new location:

"Preferences" > "Media Library" > "Music folders"

- "Remove" old locations.
- "Add" new locations.

[image]

Source [Foobar2000 A Guide To Set Up](http://www.head-fi.org/a/foobar2000-a-guide-to-set-up)

Answer (score 3):

### Use [relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths)

Foobar [supports relative paths](http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=77832&st=0&p=680060&#entry680060) for its media library. So you could place your Foobar folder (portable mode) somewhere on the same drive as your music is. After this, just remove and re-add all monitored music folders under `File » Preferences » Media Library`. Two points `..` is the indicator for relative paths.

[image]

However, [there is a bug](http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=83171). The directory level of your foobar2000 folder should not be higher than 4 or fb2k will always use absolute paths. (That's a poor implementation despite being an awesome player)

```
D:\folder1\folder2\foobar2000            <= relative paths are working 
D:\folder1\folder2\folder3\foobar2000    <= relative paths are not working
```

---

### Use the [foo_playlist_revive](http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=73910) plugin

> foo_playlist_revive makes the dead items in the playlist alive again by replacing them with the matching ones in media library.
>   A handy util for those who often move or rename their media files/folders.